# Shortcode doesn't work on ajax call in Wordpress

Tags: ajax, wordpress, caching, shortcode

I have big problem with loading ajax content in Wordpress. Ajax loading works but inside loaded file is shortcode which is show as plain text. I tried many many solutions that supposed to work but none of it works... My code is:

`echo do_shortcode( apply_filters( 'the_content', $post->post_content ) );`

But even if I hard code shortcode it still show as plain text. Actually I use **Content no cache** plugin but I tried different things and result is the same. I need to execute this shortcode. I need to use ajax to avoid cache. Any ideas?

This is my whole code for now:

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_showBanner', 'showBanner' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_showBanner', 'showBanner' );

function showBanner() {
    echo do_shortcode( '[adrotate group="1"]' );
    wp_die();
} 

function getBanner() {

echo '<div class="adr"></div>
<script>
window.addEventListener( "load", function() {
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.open("POST", "' . admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) . '", true);
    xhttp.setRequestHeader( "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;");
    xhttp.onload = function () {
        if (this.status >= 200 && this.status < 400) {
            document.querySelector( ".adr" ).innerHTML = this.responseText;
        } else {
            document.querySelector( ".adr" ).innerHTML = "Error";
        }
    };
    xhttp.send("action=showBanner");
});
</script>';
```

}

Comment: Hi, maybe is it related to the way you manage ajax. Do you use the main `wp.ajax` function?

Il your JS client expects plain-text or json, it could explain your problem.

Comment: Please show the PHP of your ajax action.

Comment: I have edited and paste my code for now (which is a little bit different than before but works exactly the same)

Comment: where are you registering the shortcode? please check wp built in any shortcode to check if none of shortcode is working!!

Comment: It's registered by plugin AdRotate – that is why I did not include this. But it works. Tested.

Comment: What is the value of `this.responseText` in your ajax response?

Comment: There is none. Because ajax return dokument error 400 (as I remember, because I dont have computer for few days). But the content of this document is "0". Even if I hardcode something different than shortcode.

Comment: This doesn't specifically address ajax issues, but you could call the named php function  in your showBanner() function instead of the shortcode.